# Where do I place complex business logic when using the Clean Architecture and Mediator patterns in the Application layer of a .net core application

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, cqrs, clean-architecture, mediator

I recently switched to using the CQRS and Mediator pattern for my in ASP.NET Core application. My entire application is using clean architecture best practices (Domain, Application, Infrastructure, Presentation).

Ever since I started using the mediator pattern I am a bit confused in my Application layer.

I currently have a folder called Features in my Application layer that has something like this for example:

- Features

  - Product

    - Commands

      - CreateProduct

        - Dto, Command, CommmandHandler...
    - Queries

      - GetAllProducts

        - Dto, Query, QueryHandler...

This is very easy to understand when we are just doing simple crud. I just inject my repositories and work with them in the handlers to do what I need to do.

**My question is:** Where do I put complex/re-usable business logic calculations for products? Should I be creating a Services folder in my Application layer that contains a ProductService? I am assuming functions in this service would return my actual domain entities and not my Dtos. Then my handlers can call these services as needed and map to Dtos if necessary.

Pre-mediator CQRS this is exactly what I did. I would have a Services folder in my Application layer that would inject repositories and do whatever custom product work that needs to be done. Then my controllers would inject my services and map to dtos.

Comment: Could you please tell us about differences between `Application` and `Presentation`? As i know `Application` itself is a presentation, ie it is consumer of all layers under it. There might be many consumers - other applications - for those layers.

Comment: `Business Logic Layer` is an essential part of any domain, so you put your logic in this layer whether you call it `Application` or `MyApplicationName.Services`. `Application` is not a good name for logic layer.

Comment: @Ryan When I say Application I mean the Application Core and when I say Presentation I mean the Web API project.

Comment: Finally, Where do you put the Business Logic? I have the same question...

Answer (score 0):

A mediator shouldn't change much about how you're organizing your code. It is not generally recommended to call commands within commands. Therefore, you can go on and create a "Common" folder within "Features/Products" and put your logic there. This can in turn take the form of extension methods or service/helper classes. It is also okay to sometimes duplicate code within your commands in case the repetition is incidental and cannot be extracted into something independently meaningful.